# Tooltip for each item in combobox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm trying to add a tooltip for each username(CreatedBy) in my combobox in case the user name is too long for the width of the combobox.

I know this question has been asked a million times, I've tried using Style.Triggers method and I have also tried 
ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedCreatedBy.ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CreatedBys.DefaultView}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCreatedBy,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="CreatedBy" DisplayMemberPath="CreatedBy" ToolTip="{Binding SelectedCreatedBy}" 
    Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="12" Height="22" Width="85" FontSize="11" IsEditable="{Binding IsCreatedByEditable}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
```

Edit: I found the solution and I will post the code here

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CreatedBys.DefaultView}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCreatedBy,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="CreatedBy" DisplayMemberPath="CreatedBy" ToolTip="{Binding SelectedCreatedBy}" 
          Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="12" Height="22" Width="85" FontSize="11" IsEditable="{Binding IsCreatedByEditable}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip" Value="{Binding CreatedBy}" />
    </Style>
      </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want a tool tip to appear for each of your combo box choices (not just the selected one). If that's the case, add the following code inside your `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding CreatedBy}"
            ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
            />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The `ItemTemplate` defines a `TextBlock` for each item with a `ToolTip` bound to the `ToolTip` property of your view model. The `ItemContainerStyle` stretches the `ComboBoxItem` so that the tool tip appears even if the mouse is not directly on the text but over the item.

Comment: I got this error message when I tried using your suggestion. 

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message='Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemTemplate' threw an exception.' Line number '169' and line position '71'.

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Brooke Try removing the `DisplayMemberPath` property from your `ComboBox`. You won't need it anymore since the `TextBlock` is binding directly to the `CreatedBy` property.

Comment: No errors trying to build this time but there aren't any tooltips working, also by default the combobox would display (ALL) then when you click there's other options, right now it's showing System.Datarowview by default when nothing is clicked.

Comment: It sounds like the bindings aren't right. Would you mind pasting your view model code (as simplified as possible)? You can append your question with the added code.

Comment: Ok I went ahead and added it above, the entire model code is huge so I just put the section involving the combobox

Comment: @Brooke Actually, your original XAML in the question was fine. What I would like to see is your view model: the object that's being bound to the `ComboBox`.

Comment: I found the solution and went ahead and added it to my original question. Thank you for your help.